# fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory, C/C++ Problem

Tags: c, ubuntu, linux-kernel, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to compile a code that I downloaded from GitHub https://github.com/severinson/VLC-driver on Eclipse CDT 3.8.1 and using ubuntu 16.04 and kernel version is 4.13.0-041300-lowlatency (because this project works on Xenomai Kernel) and getting this error:

```
fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory, 
external location: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-041300-lowlatency/include/linux/linkage.h  C/C++ Problem
```

and unresolved inclusion for the header files:

```
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/io.h>
```

I searched for this error on various website, I came to know that I have to make some changes to Makefile and there is no asm directory in /usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-041300/include, instead there is a directory named asm-generic.

Can someone help me to resolve this error and the unresolved inclusions?
[image: screenshot for error here]
[image: Makefile here]
[image: Error External Location here]
[image: headerfile path here]

Comment: Smells like some lib isn't installed correctly, or some path is missing (like gcc `-I`). The compiler can't find a library header. Other than that, it's not really possible to answer without more details.

Comment: You might be missing the headers... `sudo apt install linux-headers-4.15.0-58-generic`. Impossible to say with this little information.

Comment: I don't know why you get this particular "No such file or directory" error since it looks as if you have the linux-headers package installed. However, if you are building https://github.com/severinson/VLC-driver then building it for a standard  Ubuntu kernel is doomed to fail because it needs a kernel with Xenomai support built in.

Comment: @IanAbbott, I am doing the same project which you have mentioned in your comment. I am working on this kind of project for the first time and I am really very confused about how to do it, can you please tell me how to get a kernel with Xenomai support built-in? I am compiling the code on Eclipse 3.8.1 and right now the fatal error has been resolved, but I am getting "make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop. C/C++ Problem" as a error.

Comment: Actually, with Xenomai 3 you don't necessarily need to build a special kernel. There are two available cores. The Xenomai "Cobalt" core requires a patched kernel, but the "Mercury" core can run on a normal kernel (see [Installing Xenomai 3.x](https://xenomai.org/documentation/xenomai-3/html/README.INSTALL/index.html) ). It would be better to use the "lowlatency" Ubuntu kernel packages (linux-lowlatency, linux-image-lowlatency, etc.) instead of the "generic" kernel packages.

Comment: @IanAbbott I have installed a lowlatency ubuntu kernel package, and I am still having the same errors. What should I do to resolve these errors? I have edited my question, so you can have a look on my query.

Comment: Your makefile does not look like it is suitable for building a kernel module. (I assume that you know that the source you are trying to build is for a kernel module.) I'm also confused why it is using a compiler for an ARM processor.